# Pinecone MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='controller."asia-southeast1-gcp-free" ', port=443)

Tags: python, pinecone

I have this script in my init:

```
pinecone.init(
    api_key=os.environ["PINECONE_API_KEY"],
    environment=os.environ["PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT_REGION"]
)
```

And I set PINECONE_ENVIRONMENT_REGION = "asia-southeast1-gcp-free" in my .env

But it returns error when I run the below:

```
embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(chunk_size=1)
Pinecone.from_documents(
    documents, embeddings, index_name=os.environ["PINECONE_INDEX_NAME"]
)
```

And the error below:

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='controller."asia-southeast1-gcp-free" ', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', InvalidURL('URL can't contain control characters. 'controller."asia-southeast1-gcp-free" ' (found at least ' ')')))

I tried removing the whitespaces from the metadata but it still return the same error